# Notepad/Notepad++ Column Formatting

Tags: alignment, type-conversion, notepad++, vertical-alignment, notepad

I have to convert an .xlsx file to text such that it looks like the following:

```
0001      2-5-9
00002     2-6-9
003       2-7-9
```

But when I convert it to a .txt file I end up with the following:

```
0001     2-5-9
      00002    2-6-9
  0003     2-7-9
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  I've tried Notepad++ already, but I can't figure out how to fix it using that.  I've tried code alignment but there's no consistent reference point in the data set such as = or , to align by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Excel for this too. Try **Save As** and search for e.g. Formatted Text (Space delimited) (*.prn). I don't know exactly because I have a German GUI. Save this file and open with Notepad++ for your needs.